# PHP - Count unique in an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, unique, counting

I have a PHP array which contains objects like this

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [label] => Test 1
        [session] => 2
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [label] => Test 2
        [session] => 2
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [label] => Test 3
        [session] => 42
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [label] => Test 4
        [session] => 9
    )
 )
```

I am trying to count the number of unique sessions within this array.  I can do it when the whole thing is an array, but I am struggling to work it out when the array contains objects.

Do I need to convert the objects into arrays or is there a way of doing it with the data in its current format?

Comment: How are you defining unique?  `Array entry[session]` only, or must both fields be different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php :

> ```
> Version    Description
>
>  7.0.0     Added the ability for the input parameter to be an array of objects.
> ```

Use array_column to generate new keys using the session column values.  This effectively removes duplicate keys.

Code:  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JA8Ka))

```
$array = [
    (object)['label' => 'Test 1', 'session' => 2],
    (object)['label' => 'Test 2', 'session' => 2],
    (object)['label' => 'Test 3', 'session' => 42],
    (object)['label' => 'Test 4', 'session' => 9],
];
echo sizeof(array_column($array, null, 'session'));
```

Output:

```
3
```

Or in a loop:

```
foreach ($array as $obj) {
    $result[$obj->session] = null;
}
echo sizeof($result);
```

Both techniques avoid the extra function call of `array_unique` and leverage the fact that arrays cannot store duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code and here created sample data

```
$comments= array();
$comment = new stdClass;
$comment->label = 'Test 1';
$comment->session = '2';
array_push($comments, $comment);
$comment = new stdClass;
$comment->label = 'Test 2';
$comment->session = '2';
array_push($comments, $comment);
$comment = new stdClass;
$comment->label = 'Test 3';
$comment->session = '42';
array_push($comments, $comment);
$comment = new stdClass;
$comment->label = 'Test 4';
$comment->session = '9';
array_push($comments, $comment);
```

Here is code I tried to get the unique value. this way you can get any field unique value

```
$uniques = array();
foreach ($comments as $obj) {
    $uniques[$obj->session] = $obj;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($uniques);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to only keep the value of `session` in the array, then use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove the duplicate entries and finally [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) the unique items.

If for example your array variable is called `$array`:

```
$result = array_map(function($x){
    return $x->session;
}, $array);

echo count(array_unique($result));
```

That will result in:

> 3

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/6ci8h)

Answer (score -2):

The object within an array can be accessed with `$array[0]` where the `0` stands for the object. To access the objects property you can do `$object->session`.

To go throught every objects session property you can do:

```
foreach ($array as $object) {
    echo $object->session . "<br/>";
}
```